# How can I get my search box tabs to remain active when clicking between them?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's a jsfiddle containing the search box code: http://jsfiddle.net/m1ym110r/

I'm trying to create a search box with tabs that become active when selected.  My search boxes cycle through correctly as the tabs are clicked but the tab itself won't stay active to show that it's been selected.

Any insight would be much appreciated as I've been stuck on this for a while now and can't figure out for the life of me why the tabs aren't remaining active every time I click one.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="widget">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
        <li><a href="#pubmed" onClick="expandcontent('sc1', this)">PubMed</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#databases" onClick="expandcontent('sc2', this)">Databases</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#uptodate" onClick="expandcontent('sc3', this)">UpToDate</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#ejournals" onClick="expandcontent('sc4', this)">E-Journals</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#ebooks" onClick="expandcontent('sc5', this)">E-Books</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#catalog" onClick="expandcontent('sc6', this)">Catalog</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#site" onClick="expandcontent('sc7', this)">Website</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="sc1">
            <div class="tab-content-inner">
                <form action="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?holding=umiamilib_fft" class="SSCentralSearchSearchForm" name="searchForm" method="post" target="new">
                    <input name="SS_LibHash" value="FY6AF6XB5M" type="hidden" />
                    <input name="locale" value="en-us" type="hidden" />
                    <input name="action" value="start" type="hidden" />
                    <input name="dbIDList" value="NPM" type="hidden" />
                    <input style="width:75%" class="SSCentralSearchSearchCriteria" value="" name="term" type="text" size="40" maxlength="1000" placeholder="Search PubMed" />
                    <input class="SSCentralSearchSearchTermSubmit" type="submit" value="Search" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="sc2">
            <div class="tab-content-inner">
                <form action="http://FY6AF6XB5M.cs.serialssolutions.com/results" class="SSCentralSearchSearchForm" name="searchForm" method="post" target="new">
                    <input name="SS_LibHash" value="FY6AF6XB5M" type="hidden" />
                    <input name="locale" value="en-us" type="hidden" />
                    <input name="action" value="start" type="hidden" />
                    <input name="dbIDList" value="RYA,ACG,DNW,AQP,FFV,RWY,GLY,BDR,IDH,BID,BZP,DNL,CUI,CUJ,CVD,CVR,QTP,CZQ,CZZ,DCL,DGT,NPM,4F6,BKL,RTO,FYW,5MB,5MA,EKG,EGQ,DOK,66L" type="hidden" />
                    <input class="SSCentralSearchSearchCriteria" value="" name="term" type="text" size="40" maxlength="300" style="width:75%;" placeholder="Search Databases" />
                    <select class="SSCentralSearchSearchType" name="field">
                        <option value="title">Title</option>
                        <option value="author">Author</option>
                        <option value="full_text">Full Text</option>
                        <option value="keyword" selected="selected">Keyword</option>
                        <option value="subject">Subject</option>
                        <option value="abstract">Abstract</option>
                        <option value="isbn">ISBN</option>
                        <option value="issn">ISSN</option>
                        <option value="any">Any</option>
                    </select>
                    <input name="catID" value="102527" type="hidden" />
                    <input class="SSCentralSearchSearchTermSubmit" type="submit" value="Search" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="sc3">
            <div class="tab-content-inner">
                <form action="http://www.uptodate.com/contents/search" class="SSCentralSearchSearchForm" name="searchForm" method="post" target="new">
                    <input name="SS_LibHash" value="FY6AF6XB5M" type="hidden" />
                    <input name="locale" value="en-us" type="hidden" />
                    <input name="action" value="start" type="hidden" />
                    <input style="width:75%" class="SSCentralSearchSearchCriteria" value="" name="term" type="text" size="40" maxlength="200" placeholder="Search UpToDate" />
                    <input class="SSCentralSearchSearchTermSubmit" type="submit" value="Search" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="sc4">
            <div class="tab-content-inner">
                <form class="form-search">
                    <input type="text" class="form-search" placeholder="Find E-Journals by title" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-mini">Go</button>
                </form>
                <form>
                    <label class="radio inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="SearchType" id="rbtnContains" value="Contains" checked>Contains</label>
                    <label class="radio inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="SearchType" id="rbtnBeginsWith" value="BeginsWith">Begins With</label>
                    <label class="radio inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="SearchType" id="rbtnExactMatch" value="ExactMatch">Exact Match</label>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="sc5">
            <div class="tab-content-inner">
                <form class="form-search">
                    <input type="text" class="form-search" placeholder="Find E-Books by keyword, title or author" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-mini">Go</button>
                </form>
                <form>
                    <label>Search By:
                        <select name="Ntk">
                            <option value="Keyword" selected>Keywords</option>
                            <option value="Title">Title</option>
                            <option value="Author">Author</option>
                            <option value="Subject">Subject Heading</option>
                        </select>
                    </label> <a href="/search/external/ebooks">E-book Collections</a>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="sc6">
            <div class="tab-content-inner">
                <form class="form-search">
                    <input type="text" class="form-search" placeholder="Search Catalog" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-mini">Go</button>
                </form>
                <form>
                    <label>Search By:
                        <select name="Ntk">
                            <option value="Keyword" selected>Keywords</option>
                            <option value="Title">Title</option>
                            <option value="Author">Author</option>
                            <option value="Subject">Subject Heading</option>
                            <option value="ISBN">ISBN/ISSN</option>
                            <option value="Call Number">Call Number</option>
                        </select>
                    </label> <a href="/search/external/catalog">Catalog Home</a>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="sc7">
            <div class="tab-content-inner">
                <form action="http://calder.med.miami.edu/pages/search.html" id="site">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="002423873606424653806:kpmotam5cds">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:11">
                    <input id="searchbox" type="text" name="q" size="18" value="Search this site" maxlength=200 onFocus="value=''">&nbsp;</form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#widget {
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
#widget select {
    -webkit-appearance:menulist;
}
#widget {
    width:450px;
}
#widget #tabs {
    max-width:450px;
    height:21px;
    margin-bottom:0;
    font-size:12px;
    border-bottom:none;
}
#widget label, input[type="text"] {
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans serif;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#widget #tabs li a {
    line-height:20px;
}
#widget #databases label {
    width:25%;
}
#widget #ejournals label {
    width:20%;
}
#widget .tab-content {
    max-width:405px;
    width:450px;
    height:75px;
    max-height:75px;
    margin:;
    padding-top:;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color:#de752f;
    border:1px solid #dcd6be;
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#widget .nav-tabs > .active > a, #widget .nav-tabs > .active > a:hover {
    color:#F5E9B8;
    cursor:default;
    background-color:#de752f;
    border:none;
}
#widget .nav-tabs li a {
    max-height:24px;
    padding:4px 3px 4px 2px;
    color:#D9E0BF;
    ;
    background-color:#7B9A70;
    border:none;
}
#widget .nav-tabs li.active {
    color:#de752f;
}
#widget .nav-tabs li a:hover {
    color:#F5E9B8;
    background-color:#de752f;
    border:none;
}
#widget #tabs li {
    max-height:24px;
    padding-bottom:1px;
}
#widget .tab-content-inner {
    margin:18px 10px 18px 10px;
    line-height:2.0em;
}
#widget #databases .tab-content-inner {
    margin:6px 10px 5px;
}
#widget #ejournals .tab-content-inner {
    margin:6px 10px 5px;
}
#widget #pubmed .tab-content-inner {
    margin:14px 10px 5px;
}
#widget #ejournals .tab-content-inner {
    margin:6px 10px 5px;
}
#widget #catalog .tab-content-inner {
    margin:6px 10px 5px;
}
#widget #catalog .tab-content-inner label {
    margin-bottom:0;
    padding-top:4px;
    font-size:12px;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    zoom:1;
    width:50%;
}
#widget #ebooks .tab-content-inner {
    margin:6px 10px 5px;
}
#widget #ebooks .tab-content-inner label {
    margin-bottom:0;
    padding-top:4px;
    font-size:12px;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    zoom:1;
    width:50%;
}
#widget .tab-content-inner form {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
#widget select {
    margin:0;
    padding:0px;
    height:20px;
    width:70%;
    font-size:12px;
}
#widget .tab-content-inner form input[type="text"] {
    padding:2px 6px 1px;
    width:85%;
}
#widget #wdgtPatient-problem, #widget #wdgtIntervention {
    width:40%;
}
#widget #wdgtDrug-name {
    display:none;
}
#widget .tab-pane {
    margin-top:0px;
}
#widget label {
    color:#4F4F4F;
}
#widget a, #widget a:link, #widget a:visited {
    color:#0680CD;
}
.nav-tabs:before, .nav-pills:before, .nav-tabs:after, .nav-pills:after {
    display:table;
    line-height:0;
    content:""
}
.nav-tabs:after, .nav-pills:after {
    clear:both
}
.nav-tabs>li, .nav-pills>li {
    float:left
}
.nav-tabs>li>a, .nav-pills>li>a {
    padding-right:12px;
    padding-left:12px;
    margin-right:2px;
    line-height:14px
}
.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd
}
.nav-tabs>li {
    margin-bottom:-1px
}
.nav-tabs>li>a {
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    line-height:20px;
    border:1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius:4px 4px 0 0;
    border-radius:4px 4px 0 0
}
.nav-tabs>.active>a, .nav-tabs>.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>.active>a:focus {
    color:#D9E0BF;
    cursor:default;
    background-color:#de752f;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom-color:transparent
}
.tab-content>.tab-pane, .pill-content>.pill-pane {
    display:none
}
```

**JS**

```
/***********************************************
 * DD Tab Menu script- © Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
 * This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
 * Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
 ***********************************************/

//Set tab to intially be selected when page loads:
//[which tab (1=first tab), ID of tab content to display (or "" if no corresponding tab content)]:
var initialtab = [1, "sc1"]

//Turn menu into single level image tabs (completely hides 2nd level)?
var turntosingle = 0 //0 for no (default), 1 for yes

//Disable hyperlinks in 1st level tab images?
var disabletablinks = 0 //0 for no (default), 1 for yes


////////Stop editting////////////////

var previoustab = ""

if (turntosingle == 1) document.write('<style type="text/css">\n#tabs{display: none;}\n</style>')

function expandcontent(cid, aobject) {
    if (disabletablinks == 1) aobject.onclick = new Function("return false")
    if (document.getElementById && turntosingle == 0) {
        highlighttab(aobject)
        if (previoustab != "") document.getElementById(previoustab).style.display = "none"
        if (cid != "") {
            document.getElementById(cid).style.display = "block"
            previoustab = cid
        }
    }
}

function highlighttab(aobject) {
    if (typeof tabobjlinks == "undefined") collectddtabs()
    for (i = 0; i < tabobjlinks.length; i++)
    tabobjlinks[i].className = ""
    aobject.className = "current"
}

function collectddtabs() {
    var tabobj = document.getElementById("tabs")
    tabobjlinks = tabobj.getElementsByTagName("A")
}

function do_onload() {
    collectddtabs()
    expandcontent(initialtab[1], tabobjlinks[initialtab[0] - 1])
}

if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", do_onload, false)
else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", do_onload)
else if (document.getElementById) window.onload = do_onload
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Your question could use a formatting change since it does not appear as you typed it. Also when you use links to jsfiddle you are to include a minimal working example in the question.

Comment: It's no wonder my html isn't working if I can't even format my question on here correctly.  :/

Comment: Thank you for your help with that Matt.

Comment: You need to add `;` at the end of your lines of code in js, and you should wrap your for loop contents in `{}`, same goes for if statements

Comment: You should by a new keyboard it looks like some of your keys `;,{,}` are not working :P

Comment: Thanks for calling out the lack of proper punctuation in the code. I'm new to html and css and can barely manage with them as it is, trying to factor in javascript with zero knowledge of the language is proving disastrous.  That half a code academy js course I've taken isn't really helping yet ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is what you're trying to do. I took a completely different approach, your code sort of all over the place. Try to avoid document.write as best as you can. I used jQuery, so if you want this to work on your own personal website you'll need to include the following line of code at the top of your header (before you call all your jQuery functions or include external links to your jQuery files):

- `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/m1ym110r/2/) is the jsfiddle I have created for you

Here is the code I created:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var numberOfTabs = $("#tabs>li").length;
    $("#tabs>li:eq(0)").addClass("active");
    $(".tab-pane").hide();
    $(".tab-pane:eq(0)").show();
    $("#tabs>li").click(function () {
        $("#tabs>li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        var index = $(this).index("#tabs>li");
        $(".tab-pane").hide();
        $(".tab-pane:eq(" + index + ")").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly on my site!  Seriously, what a relief to finally see those tabs cycle through correctly and become active.  Thank you ctwheels for writing a JS code that not only works but I can study for proper punctuation.  Major props!!

Comment: @unight You are very welcome, if you want any explanations of the code, feel free to ask me